# How can I Scrape Business Email Contact with python?

Tags: python

this morning I wanted to create a little Software/Script in Python, it was 6am when I started and now I'm about to become crazy because it's 22pm and I have nothing that works.

So basically, I want to do this: Given an Instagram Username, scrape the Name, Number of followers and the business contact email.

I found out that going to the page source will give me this info (let's consider only the email for now): https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HkDt.jpg

Any idea about how I can do that? I try many different things and nothing is working. I don't know what to do. I tried downloading the page and parsing the text looking for "business_email" but I have no idea about how to implement it and extracting the data I'm looking for, I know it's a simple task, but I'm a total noob and I haven't been coding for years.

Can someone tell me how to do it? Or at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you show some code for what you've already attempted? Or provide a sample URL endpoint and sample output for what you'd like.

Comment: You'll almost certainly have to use Instagram's API, see here: https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram. Also, I sincerely doubt that all instagram users have their name and email associated with their account....

Comment: I couldn't write any code. I tried different things to test the approach (like b4s and re) but I couldn't make it work not even following examples, so I had no idea about how to implement it.
Also, the Instagrams users are previously selected and proven to have a Business Email associated

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to approach this problem. If the data you want is visible on the page, then you could scrap that info using [Beatiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). If not, then it's a little more trickier but you could extract the info for the page source using regular expressions with the [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module.